# The image MIME type is not valid or not supported

Tags: product, image

I am not able to add media from `URL` to Product

```
{ 
 "entry":{  
 "id": 0,
 "label": "ZYXEL USG 300 ICARD CONTENT FILTER 1 YIL-210011129", 
 "position":0,
 "disabled":true,
 "types":[ 
"image","small_image","thumbnail","swatch_image" ],
 "file": "http://img.bayinet.com.tr/Content/ProductImages/210011129/images/210011129.jpg", 
 "content":{ 
 "base64_encoded_data": "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASABIAAD/2wBDAAICAgICAgICAgIDAgICBAUEAgIEBQYFBQUFBQYHBgYGBgY", 
 "type": "image", 
 "name": "ZYXEL USG 300 ICARD CONTENT FILTER 1 YIL-210011129.jpg" 
} 
} 
}
```

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

You have error in your parameters which you are passing. you need to add type of image parameters like this **"type":"image/jpeg"**

**Try below code :**

```
{
    "entry":
    {
    "media_type":"image",
    "label":" products 009-5923-53081",
    "position":0,
    "disabled":false,
    "types":["image","small_image","thumbnail","swatch_image"],
    "file":"magento2",
    "content":{"base64_encoded_data":"\/9j\/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASABIAAD\/4gxYSUNDX1BST0ZJTEUAAQEAAAxITGlubwIQAABtbnRyUkdCIFhZWiAHzgACAAkABgAxAABhY3NwTVNGVAAAAABJRUMgc1JHQgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA9tYAAQAAAADTLUhQICAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABFjcHJ0AAAB",
                "type":"image\/jpeg",
                "name":"ZYXEL USG 300 ICARD CONTENT FILTER 1 YIL-210011129.jpg"
              }
    }
}
```